# JQuery UI - How to apply containment to selector that matches multiple divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Example:

```
<div>
    <div class='drop'>
        <div class='drag'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='drop'>
    </div>
    <div class='drop'>
    </div>
    <div class='drop'>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
</div>

$('div.drag').draggable({ containment: 'div.drop' });
```

Normally, if there is only 1 "div.drop" element, it works as intended. If there are more than 1(like in the example above), I thought that it would be dragged/dropped in any of the "div.drop" divs. As it turns out, it is only draggable/droppable to the first element matched by the "div.drop" selector.

Is there a workaround for this(that is, make it contained/droppable/draggable only in the  "div.drop" divs)?

EDIT: I guess you are right guys. After some introspection, I realized that I didn't go for your suggested solutions since there are padding between the divs and I don't want the the "div.drag" divs to be dropped on the padded area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It don't works like that !!
The containment is to constraint bound of dragging.

You want drag and drop.
Then you have to configure drag for div.grag:

```
$('div.drag').draggable();
```

And configure drop for div.drop:

```
$('div.drop').droppable();
```

You can add containment for your drag element with your first div level:

```
<div id='dragZone'>
    <div class='drop'>
        <div class='drag'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='drop'>
    </div>
</div>


$('div.drag').draggable({ containment: '#dragZone'});
```

Answer (score 1):

`containment` restricts the movement of a draggable within the bounds of the given element(s). You could set `containment` to the parent of the `div.drop`s.

You should make the `div.drop`s droppable, append the draggable on drop, and use the `revert: 'invalid'` option so that the draggable reverts if it's not dropped on a droppable

```
$('div.drop').droppable({drop: function(e, ui) {
    ui.draggable.appendTo(this);
}});
$('div.drag').draggable({
    helper: 'clone', 
    revert: 'invalid'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As the guys have pointed out the containment [selector](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-containment) does not work like that as it *Constrains dragging to within the bounds of the specified element or region*.

You could try something like below:

JQuery References:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="dragContainer">    
<div class='drop'> 
    <div class='drag'>drag</div>     
</div>     
<div class='drop'>drop
</div>     
<div class='drop'>drop
</div>     
<div class='drop'>drop
</div>     
<div class='nodrop'>
</div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('div.drag').draggable({ containment: '#dragContainer', revert: "invalid" });

  $('div.drop').droppable( {
    drop: handleDropEvent
  } );

function handleDropEvent( event, ui ) {
  var draggable = ui.draggable;
  alert( 'Ok to drop here onto me!' );
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do try my code

```
<style>
.container {
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
.container img {
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
}
.draggable {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #F90;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  float: top;
}
.draggable.is-pointer-down {
  background: #09F;
  z-index: 2; /* above other draggies */
}
.draggable.is-dragging { opacity: 0.7; }
 </style>
  <script>
$(document).ready( function() {
  var $draggables = $('.draggable').draggabilly({
    // contain to parent element
        **containment: "#box"**
  });
});
</script>
```

Hello. I think this might help you :)

```
<div class="container" id="box">
```

and my images are inside this div.